# Alternatives to using arrows when accessing vi command history

Tags: vim, command, vi

In vi/vim, when you execute commands or searches they get added to a list of previous commands. And, just like in shell, they can be retrieved via the up or down arrow keys. These are very inconvenient, is there any other way to traverse the history without using the arrows keys?

Comment: For those who want to move this to SU, please read [Vim questions: SO or SU](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su). SO currently has 4965 Vim questions compared to 939 on SU. In my personal opinion, SO **is** the place to ask about Vim.

Comment: I've posted it in my comment?!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes. In normal mode `q:` opens a vim window with the command history. You can work in it like any other vim buffer. Enter executes a command. `q/` and `q?` do the same for searches.

Also, while you are typing a command, you can press Ctrl-F to open the command-line window and continue editing the command there.

Comment: also I was not aware that `q/` and `q?` where options

Comment: "Hey, buddy, come here, there's a guy who has just found the holy grail!"

Answer (score 29):

You can use `ctrl-n` and `ctrl-p` in the command line to traverse the history and to move between wild card matches. See `:help c_CTRL-N`.

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: This is great for recent commands. If you want only commands that begin with a specific string, this won't work quite as well. If you type in `:vs` and then hit up and down arrow, it will jump between previous commands that began with `:vs`, while `ctrl-n`/`ctrl-p` will only move through the immediate history

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes I get to press `q:` and that brings me a Command Line buffer with the most recent commands. You can navigate it with h, j, k, l and hitting Enter on desired command.

Answer (score 0):

You can create command-line mode mappings to achieve this. You could for example use `<Ctrl-j>` and `<Ctrl-p>` as alternatives to arrow down and up:

```
cnoremap <C-j> <Down>
cnoremap <C-k> <Up>
```